# Why does this piece of code not display on my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I added the code below to headers and footers so it would load before the `</body>` of the WordPress page and it doesn't display anything.

```
<script defer src="https://connect.podium.com/widget.js#API_TOKEN=91c679dc-e819-4506-851e-f4cd664249ae" id="podium-widget" data-api-token="91c679dc-e819-4506-851e-f4cd664249ae"></script>
```

It should display the widget when installed on a webpage.

Comment: Please post the code you inserted and the relevant parts you posted them in.

Comment: It is working properly. https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/r6juLvd7/1/

Comment: Clear the Cache of your website , or try to load it in incognito window